# NullPointerException numa consulta do Junit!

Tags: junit

Observem o código abaixo;

```
@Sql(statements = { 
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (1,'segundo  grupo')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (2,'primeiro  grupo')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES  (3,'Grupo 1')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES  (4,'Grupo 2')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES  (5,'Grupo 3')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES  (6,'Grupo 4')",
        "INSERT INTO GrupoTipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES  (7,'Grupo 5')",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (137,'Piso salarial de professores','Descrição teste 1','Critério teste 1',15,1,6596)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (138,'Acumulação de cargos','Descrição teste 2','Critério teste 2',15,2,6596)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (96,'Falecidos percebendo remuneração','Descrição teste 3','Critério teste 3',15,3,6596)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (139,'CPFs inválidos na base da Receita Federal','Descrição teste 4','Critério teste 4',15,4,6596)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (140,'Servidores acima de 75 anos ainda em atividade','Descrição teste 5','123456',15,1,6596)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (141,'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam hendrerit pulvinar sagittis posuere.','1','3',2,3,6632)",
        "INSERT INTO TipoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,Descricao,Criterio,PrazoPadrao,CodigoGrupo,CodigoUsuarioResponsavel) VALUES (16,'Acumulação2','Ligado2','oi tudo bem 2',20,2,6632)",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (1,'A encaminhar','- ')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (2,'Aguardando esclarecimento','Aguardando esclarecimento')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (3,'Esclarecimento iniciado','Esclarecimento iniciado')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (4,'Esclarecimento pronto para ser enviado ao TCE','Esclarecimento pronto para ser enviado ao TCE')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (5,'Esclarecimento enviado ao TCE','Esclarecimento enviado ao TCE')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (6,'Em análise pela equipe de auditoria','Em análise no TCE')",
        "INSERT INTO SituacaoIndicio (Codigo,Nome,NomeUsuarioExterno) VALUES (7,'Analisado','Analisado pelo TCE')",
        "INSERT INTO NaturezaIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (1,'Auditoria vertical')",
        "INSERT INTO NaturezaIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (2,'Auditoria horizontal manual')",
        "INSERT INTO NaturezaIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (3,'Auditoria horizontal automática')",
        "INSERT INTO NaturezaIndicio (Codigo,Nome) VALUES (4,'Demanda do cidadão')",
        "INSERT INTO Indicio (Codigo,CodigoTipoIndicio,CodigoUJ,CPFServidor,Descricao,Valor,CodigoNaturezaIndicio,NomeServidor,CodigoTipoVinculo,NomeTipoVinculo,CodigoCargo,NomeCargo,DataAdmissao,ChaveTrilha,Prazo,CodigoUsuarioProprietario,CodigoSituacaoAtual,DataUltimaMovimentacao,MatriculaServidorUJ) VALUES (1,16,3,'80445500700','descrição sucinta do que se trata o problema',1500.0000,1,'douglas',1,'paula','1','paulo','2019-06-09','15',15,1564,1,'2019-06-10 15:45:49.410','1')" })
public class IndicioDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private IndicioDAO indicioDAO;

    @Test
    public void findByIdIndicio() {
        IndicioEntity result = indicioDAO.getPorId(1);
        assertThat(result, notNullValue());

    }
```

Apesar de realizar uma consulta simples ele ainda está gerando um erro como podem ver abaixo;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bm.got.pt.teste.test1.pessoal.dao.IndicioDAOTest.findByIdIndicio(IndicioDAOTest.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

**Porque será que está dando esse problema?**

Comment: Pelo erro está a tentar chamar o método `findByIdIndicio` de um objeto que se encontra null.

Comment: Onde está instanciando o `indicioDAO`?

Comment: @Autowired
    private IndicioDAO indicioDAO;

Comment: Será que ele tem que ser instânciado de forma diferente?

Comment: Deu enable ao Autowired?

Comment: Sim, habilitei sim.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95769/discussion-between-mauroalmeida-and-wladyband).

Comment: Tente usar a injeção de dependência via construtor, ao invés do Autowired

Comment: @JorgeDiego como vou fazer isso no meu projeto?